# sql parse case end expression with regular expressions preg_match_all

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

I try to parse from an oracle query the content of case-end expressions. I use the following regular expr. 
`/((?<=case)[\w\s:\=\'\".\,()\<>-]*(?=end)){1}?/gi`

the sql part is:

`DECODE(
            SUM(
              CASE WHEN a.art_ind IN ('NORMAL', 'MVAR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ), 
            0, 
            1, 
            SUM(
              CASE WHEN a.art_ind IN ('NORMAL', 'MVAR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           )
          )
        )* 100, 
        2
      ) store_av,`

but I get wrong results, it gets 2 or more case-end blocks. 
Please look below. It takes 2 case-end instead of 1 
Can someone propose a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((?<=case)[\w\s:\=\'\".\,()\<>-]*?(?=end)){1}?

                                ^^
```

Make your `*` non greedy.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/21